# How to run servlet in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

Installation Details:

First I install the jdk then add a environment variable

variable name = "path"

variable value ="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin"(directory of java)

Then Extract the eclipse and tomcat

After extracting, I edit the catalina.bat from apache-tomcat-7.0.23\bin and add this:
"set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"

Then I made my first Servlet by creating new dynamic web project

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>JAVA TEST</h1>

<form action ="work.html" method ="get">

<input type="submit" value="login">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class work
 */
@WebServlet("/work.html")
public class work extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public work() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.print("<html>");
        out.print("<head>");
        out.print("<title>Login Authentication Result</title>");
        out.print("<h2>Welcome to servlet</h2>");
        out.print("<p> powered by" + getServletContext().getServerInfo()+ "</p>");
        out.print("</body>");
        out.print("</hmtl>");
        out.close();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Test3</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

[image]

I'm new to servlet. I don't know why it is always have this error when clicking the button in the index.html

[image]

I think I have the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245793/how-to-make-my-first-servlet-work?rq=1)

Comment: Add a logging statement in your class' constructor. Also, change your annotation to `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/work.html" , loadOnStartup = 1)`. Do you see the logged statement? What you've shown works fine for me.

Comment: Yes this works in the machine on comlab. So I think it is from my installation

Comment: Make sure you have a Servlet 3.0 compatible version of Tomcat.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: yes my tomcat is apache-tomcat-7.0.23

Comment: All I can suggest is to clean the project and rebuild. Then redeploy.

Comment: Still not working. :(

Comment: Did you try what I told you earlier? Check your logs when you apply those changes.

Comment: what is that logging statement?

Comment: Anything, like `System.out.println("in constructor");`

Comment: I didn't see the logging statement in the console

Comment: I think I did'nt able to configure it correctly?

Comment: I'm honestly out of ideas. Try putting your class in an actual package.

Answer (score 0):

Just configure Tomcat in eclipse!